# understanding AMFChannel in flex and message broker

Tags: apache-flex, spring, integration

I need to use AMFChannel in order to connect to RemoteObject in flex tried searching a lot but couldn;t get source to understand the two parameters being passed to the constructor ... I am using spring framework as a backend for my GUI created using flex .... canm some one explain me this integration of flex with spring or guide me to a proper resource to understand it... through which I can understand the overall scenerio... or atleast understand how this call is being made using message broker . **PLEASE SOME ONE HELP ME BY TELLING ME WHAT IS THE MEANING OF URL WE ARE PASSING TO THE  AMF CHANNEL CONSTRUCTOR**

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://static.springsource.org/spring-flex/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/ch03.html) might help some one.

The MessageBroker transparently handles the process of serialization and deserialization between the Flex AMF data format and Java.

[This link explains everything with help of example which was exactly what I was looking for](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/06/10/using-spring-blazeds-integration-10/)

some important setup information is as follows

Server side has following files
    *  testdrive/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml
    * testdrive/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flex-servlet.xml
    * testdrive/src/main/java/flex/spring/samples/product/ProductDAO.java

Client side has one file which looks like this

Step1) Initialize a messagebroker in flex-servlet.xml

```
<flex:message-broker>
        <flex:message-service
            default-channels="my-streaming-amf,my-longpolling-amf,my-polling-amf" />
        <flex:secured />
</flex:message-broker>
```

Step2)  In the same flex-servlet.xml specify one tag

```
<flex:remoting-destination ref="productService" />
```

Step 3) In app-config.xml

```
<bean id="contactService" class="org.springframework.flex.samples.product.ProductDAO">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Step 4) ProductDAO.java is the class which will exposed for the remoting

Client side can call the remote object as follows

Step 5)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

    <!-- "productService" is defined in Spring's configuration file WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml
    and provides remote access to the org.springframework.flex.samples.product.ProductDAO class --> 
    <mx:RemoteObject id="ro" destination="productService"/>

    <mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{ro.findAll.lastResult}" width="100%" height="100%"/>

    <!-- the findAll() method is defined in org.springframework.flex.samples.product.ProductDAO -->
    <mx:Button label="Get Data" click="ro.findAll()"/>

</mx:Application>
```